# With relativistic mass increase, what is velocity and distance as function of force and time?

Tags: forces, momentum, relativity

Given a known force (rate of change of momentum), if we also consider the Lorentz mass increase, I'd like to have 2 functions where velocity and distance covered are dependent on time.  I'm talking about velocities where the mass increase is not trivial.  I'm 70, and my differential equation skill, pretty good back in 1969, is completely corroded.

Comment: See my answer as user82794 therein : [Inertia on relativistic mass when particle is near speed of light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/195532/inertia-on-relativistic-mass-when-particle-is-near-speed-of-light). Note that my equation (11) for the distance travelled is identical to the equation given by Alfred Centauri in his answer in the link given above in your question. Also my equation (07) for the velocity as function of the distance travelled is identical to the equation given in jaromrax answer in the same link above.