# Relativistic particle under increasing force

Tags: special-relativity

Can it be shown that the limiting velocity of a mass is the speed of light under any nature of external force? Specifically with the example of say, a linearly increasing force F(1+bx).

I tried some cases but the integrals seemed to get too tedious for a leisurely nab at physics :p

Comment: Does the relativistic mass formula help you? If you take that formula and put v=c, you will obtain a singularity, so the mass goes to infinity. Which in some sense, provides the speed limit of a mass particle.

Comment: I was looking for something from the newton's law's perspective. Something like the force F(1+bx) itself goes to infinity, but does the velocity do so?

Comment: Well...if you want to study a relativistic particle, I guess you have to drop the newton's law :D feelsbadman

Comment: But is there any way to do so? The classic example of a constant force on a relativistic particle is in most standard books. But none involve a force which itself goes to infinity like the one above. I was curious if the same treatment could be carried out.

Comment: Take a look in my answer as user82794 herein : [Inertia on relativistic mass when particle is near speed of light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/195532/inertia-on-relativistic-mass-when-particle-is-near-speed-of-light). Look at this as an exercise of non-relativistic classical mechanics. It answers your question for constant force in one dimension (b=0).

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in seeing what happened for some specific variation of force, I'm not going to say anything useful. My approach would be to use the general result (established in a few lines in any good SR textbook) that $$\int_{u=0}^{v} \frac{d [m \gamma(u)\ \vec{u}]}{dt}. d \vec{r} = m \gamma (v) c^2 -mc^2.$$ This equates the work done by any force (defined as rate of change of relativistic linear momentum) to kinetic energy acquired. $v$ is the 'final' velocity of the body due to the continued action of the force. But, as we know, $\gamma (v)$ goes to infinity as $v$ approaches $c$, so the force would have to do an infinite amount of work to get the body up to the speed of light!

Comment: If the OP wants a dynamical argument, then a simpler one is that $m^2=E^2-p^2$ (in natural units), where $m$ is a fixed property of the particle. Therefore we always have $E>|p|$, which implies subluminal velocity. But more fundamentally this is really a kinematic fact. Combining two Lorentz transformations (which by definition have $|v|<c$) results in another Lorentz transformation. Therefore no continuous process of acceleration can bring a particle from subluminal to superluminal speed.

Comment: Yes. I was just trying to preserve something of Derangedmuon's approach.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let a 1-dimensional force  continuous, bounded and integrable
\begin{equation}
  0<f\left(x\right)<+\infty\:, \qquad 0<\int\limits_{\xi=0}^{\xi=x}f\left(\xi\right)\mathrm{d}\xi<+\infty\:, \qquad\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{+}
\tag{01}   
\end{equation}
acting on a particle initially at rest on the origin with rest mass $\;m_{0}$, see Figure. On one hand we have
\begin{equation}
 \mathrm{d}\left(mc^2\right)=f\left(\xi\right)\mathrm{d}\xi=\mathrm{d}\mathrm{W}\left(\xi\right)
\tag{02}   
\end{equation}
so integrating and considering the initial conditions
\begin{equation}
 m\left(x\right)=m_{0}+\dfrac{1}{c^{2}}\int\limits_{\xi=0}^{\xi=x}f\left(\xi\right)\mathrm{d}\xi=m_{0}+\dfrac{1}{c^{2}}\mathrm{W}\left(x\right)
\tag{03}   
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align}
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!W(x) & =\int\limits_{\xi=0}^{\xi=x}f\left(\xi\right)\mathrm{d}\xi=\text{work done by force $f(x)$ from $0$ to $x$}  \quad [W(x)> 0\:\: \forall x>0]
\\
&=\left(m-m_{0}\right)c^{2}=\text{kinetic energy of the particle}
\tag{04}  
\end{align}
and on the other hand
\begin{equation}
 f=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}t}=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\left(mv\right)}{\mathrm{d}t} =m\dfrac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}+v\dfrac{\mathrm{d}m}{\mathrm{d}t}
\tag{05}   
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
f\left(x\right)\mathrm{d}x=\frac12 m\,\mathrm{d}v^{2}+v^{2}\mathrm{d}m
\tag{06}   
\end{equation}
Replacing in (06) the term $\,\mathrm{d}m\,$ by its expression from (02)
\begin{equation}
f\left(x\right)\mathrm{d}x=\frac12 m\,\mathrm{d}v^{2}+\dfrac{v^{2}}{c^{2}}f\left(x\right)\mathrm{d}x
\tag{07}   
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{f\left(x\right)\mathrm{d}x}{m}=\frac12\dfrac{\mathrm{d}v^{2}}{\left(1-\dfrac{v^{2}}{c^{2}}\right)}
\tag{08}   
\end{equation}
Inserting  the expression (03) for $\,m\,$ and replacing $\,f\left(x\right)\mathrm{d}x \rightarrow \mathrm{d}\mathrm{W}\left(x\right)\,$ we reach the following differential equation with respect to the separated variables $\,x\,$ and $\,v^{2}\,$
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\mathrm{W}\left(x\right)}{\left[m_{0}c^{2}+\mathrm{W}\left(x\right)\vphantom{\frac12}\right]}=\frac12\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\left(\dfrac{v^{2}}{c^{2}}\right)}{\left(1\!-\!\dfrac{v^{2}}{c^{2}}\right)}
\tag{09}   
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\left[m_{0}c^{2}+\mathrm{W}\left(x\right)\vphantom{\frac12}\right]}{\hphantom{\mathrm{d}}\left[m_{0}c^{2}+\mathrm{W}\left(x\right)\vphantom{\frac12}\right]}=-\frac12 \dfrac{\mathrm{d}\left(1\!-\!\dfrac{v^{2}}{c^{2}}\right)}{\hphantom{\mathrm{d}}\left(1\!-\!\dfrac{v^{2}}{c^{2}}\right)}
\tag{10}   
\end{equation}
that is
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{d}\left(\ln\left[m_{0}c^{2}+\mathrm{W}\left(x\right)\vphantom{\tfrac12}\right]\vphantom{\frac12}\!\!\right)= \mathrm{d}\left[\ln\left(1\!-\!\dfrac{v^{2}}{c^{2}}\right)^{-\frac12}\vphantom{\frac12}\!\!\right]
\tag{11}   
\end{equation}
Considering the initial conditions the integration of (11) yields
\begin{equation}
m_{0}c^{2}+\mathrm{W}\left(x\right)=m_{0}c^{2}\left(1\!-\!\dfrac{v^{2}}{c^{2}}\right)^{-\frac12}
\tag{12}   
\end{equation}
From equations (12) and (03)
\begin{equation}
m\left(\upsilon\right)=\dfrac{m_{o}}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{\upsilon^{2}}{c^{2}}}}
\tag{13}
\end{equation}
while solving (12) with respect to $\,v\,$ we have its following expression as function of $\,x\,$
\begin{equation}
v\left(x\right)=c\sqrt{1\!-\!\left[\dfrac{m_{0} c^{2}}{m_{0}c^{2}+\mathrm{W}\left(x\right)}\right]^{2}}
\tag{14}   
\end{equation}
Since $\,\mathrm{W}\left(x\right)\,$ is a positive increasing function of $\,x\,$ and
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\mathrm{W}\left(x\right)=+\infty
\tag{15}  
\end{equation}
we have
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}v\left(x\right)=c \:, \qquad 0<v\left(x\right)<c \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{+}
\tag{16}  
\end{equation}

If we want to find the position as function of time, that is $\,x\left(t\right)\,$, then from equation (14) given that $\,v\left(x\right)=\mathrm{d}x/\mathrm{d}t\,$,  we have after separation of the variables $\,x\,$ and $\,t\,$
\begin{equation}
\left(1\!-\!\left[\dfrac{m_{0} c^{2}}{m_{0}c^{2}+\mathrm{W}\left(x\right)}\right]^{2}\right)^{-\frac12}\mathrm{d}x=c\,\mathrm{d}t
\tag{17}   
\end{equation}
To have analytic solution depends upon the possibility of analytic integration of the function of the lhs of (17).
For example in case of constant force, $\,f\left(x\right)=f_{0}>0 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^{+}\,$, the analytic solution is<sup>(1)</sup>
\begin{equation}
x\left(t\right)=\dfrac{m_{o}c^{2}}{f_{0}}\left[\sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{f_{0}t}{m_{o}c}\right)^{2}}-1\right]
\tag{18}
\end{equation}

---

<sup>(1)
See in my answer here :[Inertia on relativistic mass when particle is near speed of light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/195532/inertia-on-relativistic-mass-when-particle-is-near-speed-of-light)</sup>